# How to begin "block of string" formatting in C#?

Tags: c#, php, formatting

I have to write some queries in my C# code and had a question about formatting.  See below:

```
    string sql = "SELECT * ";
    sql += "FROM HYT_User_Vehicle_Group_Assoc ";
    sql += "INNER JOIN HYT_Vehicle_Group ON HYT_Vehicle_Group.Vehicle_Group_No = HYT_User_Vehicle_Group_Assoc.Vehicle_Group_No ";
```

Coming from PHP background, this is how I would have written it in PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM HYT_User_Vehicle_Group_Assoc
    INNER JOIN HYT_Vehicle_Group ON HYT_Vehicle_Group.Vehicle_Group_No = HYT_User_Vehicle_Group_Assoc.Vehicle_Group_No";
```

notice how I don't have to always write a `sql +=` for each new line in the string?   Is there some wayto tell C# that I'm going to begin a "block of string", such that I don't have to always type `sql +=`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup - use a [*verbatim string literal*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) by putting @ before the leading ":

```
string sql = @"SELECT *
    FROM HYT_User_Vehicle_Group_Assoc
    INNER JOIN HYT_Vehicle_Group
    ON HYT_Vehicle_Group.Vehicle_Group_No = HYT_User_Vehicle_Group_Assoc.Vehicle_Group_No";
```

Note that this also removes escaping with a backslash - one of the times it's really useful is for regular expressions and Windows file paths. To include a double-quote in a verbatim string literal, you double it:

```
string text = "Jon says, ""Verbatim string literals."" And that's all.";
```

For particularly large blocks of code-as-text, I'd probably stick them in a separate embedded resource, mind you - or use an ORM so I didn't need SQL for the majority of data access :)

For more on strings, string literals (regular and verbatim), escape sequences etc, see my [article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

```
@"Try
this!"
```

At-sign :)  Will do what you want.

Comment: `@` is not an ampersand (`&`); it's the at symbol.

Comment: I think ampersand is `&` not `@`

Comment: Nonsense @ is an ampersand and & is clearly a worm. Oops.. :X

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using @ attribute for strings spanning multiple lines. Refer [this](http://jameskovacs.com/2007/02/12/multiline-strings-in-c/) link for more details on usage.

```
sql = @"SELECT *
    FROM HYT_User_Vehicle_Group_Assoc
    INNER JOIN HYT_Vehicle_Group ON HYT_Vehicle_Group.Vehicle_Group_No = HYT_User_Vehicle_Group_Assoc.Vehicle_Group_No";
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Verbatim String Literals.

```
@"Here is my
multiline verbatim string"
```